# Blank page shown in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: firefox, jsf

I have a jsf page which works perfectly fine[Both in IE and Mozilla Firefox] when the application is deployed locally. But i deploy it at the client place and I try to access the page in mozilla FF i get a blank page but it shows up properly in IE.

Now if i do a remote desktop connection to the system where the application is deployed and try to access the same page i get to see the page correctly in both mozilla ff & IE

Is this due to some sort of network issue specific to mozilla?

If i try to see the page source by right clicking on the blank page i get to see the page source which is same when the page is rendered correctly

Comment: check the error console of FireFox.

Comment: There are no errors in console. If i continuously keep on refreshing the page i get to see the page after some 10 tries

Answer (score 0):

i guess the app is not available on the web for us to look at?

load the page while monitoring the 'network' -tab in firebug and see if there's any asset that's not loading, are which is loading very slowly?